# Com gerar o client_secret para uma API oAuth2

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou usando NodeJS, mas acredito que a pergunta pode ser util também em outras linguagens. A especificação oAuth 2 não determina o tamanho da string que deve ser gerada, só informa isso

```
VSCHAR     = %x20-7E
```

É a sequencia caracteres do ASCII. Como posso gerar essa sequencia no NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução encontrada foi criar um número inteiro e randômico e converter ele para base 36. Segue um exemplo.

```
'use strict';

const Client = function() {
     let value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 
          (999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 -     100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)) +
          100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;   

     return { secret: value.toString(36) }
};
```